# String Comparison

Tags: code-golf, string, decision-problem

You are given two strings \$a\$ and \$b\$ consisting of characters from a to z in lowercase. Let \$n\$ be the length of \$a\$. Let \$m\$ be the length of \$b\$. Let \$a'\$ be the string \$a\$ repeated \$m\$ times. Let \$b'\$ be the string \$b\$ repeated \$n\$ times. Check whether \$a'\$ is lexicographically less than \$b'\$.

Test cases:

```
a b ---> true
ac a ---> false
bekcka kwnfoe ---> true
beztbest bestbe ---> false
mcjaf mc ---> true
akboe uenvi ---> true
```

Shortest code wins.

Hint: there's a 13-byte JavaScript solution. Beat that!

Competitive answers use the `a+b<b+a` approach. A proof of this approach can be found at https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/91381?#comment-808323

Comment: Can I take input as a list of two strings?

Comment: Of course that's reasonable

Comment: @lyxal [That is actually a default since 2 days ago](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25708/91213)

Comment: @mousetail thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Is it permissible to instead return a comparison function? e.g. instead of returning two values for less than and not less than to return three values one for less than, one for greater than *and one for equal*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

<sup>Let's give these strings some oo`ṁÞƑ` :)</sup>

```
ṁÞƑ
```

A monadic Link that accepts a pair of lists of characters, \$[b, a]\$, and yields `0` when \$a'=a\times n\$ is lexicographically less than \$b'=b\times m\$ where \$\times\$ is "repeat" or `1` if not.

i.e. takes the strings in reverse order and results in the negative.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsbD845N/P//f7R6YlKyuo4CiAKhZPVYAA)** Or see the [test-suite](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzsbD845N/P9w95ZDWx/u2PRw56zD7Q93dz9qmOOWmFOcCqRDikqB1FwdhywgR8HWTgHI0Yz8/z9RIYkrMVkhkSspNTs5O1EhuzwvLT8VyKsqSUotLlEAEUmpXLnJWYlpCrnJXInZSfmpCqWpeWWZXIkKicnJIO3JSQqJAA).

#### How?

We actually only need to check the first up to \$m+n\$ characters of the two augmented strings. This gets these by moulding each string like the input pair, e.g. `['ab', 'xyz']` gives `['ab', 'aba']` and `['xy', 'zxy']`. There is no need to flatten these before comparing them since their relative sort order is unaffected due to them having the same shape as each other.

```
ṁÞƑ - Link: pair of strings, X = [b, a]
  Ƒ - is X invariant under?:
 Þ  -   sort (the elements, e, of) X by:
ṁ   -     (e) mould like (X)
```

#### Worked Example

```
a = 'abcdefgh' -> n = 8
b = 'pqrst' -> m = 5
X = [b, a] = ['pqrst', 'abcdefgh']
b ṁ X = ['pqrst', 'pqrstpqr']
  ...this is the first n+m=13 characters of b',
         'pqrstpqrstpqrstpqrstpqrstpqrstpqrstpqrst', split after m = 5 characters
a ṁ X = ['abcde', 'fghabcde']
  ...this is the first n+m=13 characters of a',
         'abcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefghabcdefgh', split after m = 5 characters
(a ṁ X) < (b ṁ X) so the sorting, `ṁÞ`, reverses X
checking for invariance with `ṁÞƑ` therefore gives 0 indicating that a' < b'
```

Answer (score 14):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), 18 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:a+b<b+a
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TY9dDoIwDMffd4pmTyDDZ0PEk5CYFrc4B4OMoehVfCExegAv4Rm8jZA9SB_atP39-3F_tVd_bOz4UHnx7L1KN-8KazogoKAME9pSgqHx_QyQA-ccgSBN0x1410uGJWBIFVadZCRNaRDMxapGLjiSN0-y8zA7kktJXZ5QQV0upxqa1L20Z_2vTrvXXVtpH_HC8pgx1bj5TrHaCwfaQo1t1HkXIDHEGYPJWqetj1Q0kbFwMQvvjGOIPw)

#### How?

\$a+b \lesseqqgtr b+a \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad a+a+b \lesseqqgtr a+b+a \lesseqqgtr b+a+a  \quad\cdots\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad m\times a+b \lesseqqgtr b+ m\times a \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad m\times a+b+b \lesseqqgtr b+m\times a+b \lesseqqgtr b+b+ m\times a \quad\cdots\quad\Leftrightarrow\quad m\times a+n\times b \lesseqqgtr n\times b+ m\times a \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad m\times a \lesseqqgtr n\times b\$

Comment: It took me a minute to realize why this works!

Comment: Great explanation. However, I believe it is not appropriate to use the \$\Leftrightarrow\$ symbol here as many of the steps are not reversible. You have to use a separate, albeit very straightforward, argument to prove \$m \times a < n \times b \Rightarrow a + b < b + a\$.

Comment: @HuỳnhTrầnKhanh It works both ways as we always cover all possibilities. If we have `l.h.s.1 < or = or > r.h.s.1 => l.h.s.2 < or = or > r.h.s.2` then, e.g., `l.h.s.2 < r.h.s.2 => l.h.s.1 < r.h.s.1` because otherwise `l.h.s.1 = or > r.h.s.1` from which as established first `=> l.h.s.2 = or > r.h.s.2`, contradiction.

Answer (score 6):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 13 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>a+b<b+a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFRDoAgCADQu/Clc3WC8C5g6AonLVsdn9476aVZ7uN6lmG7eEUnzIyZEm@cyIuNaV3Wbi3UACxalCAG0G9UE4jRfw)

Probably the 13 byte JS solution mentioned in the challenge. Ports loopy walt's Python answer.

Answer (score 5):

## [Wolfram Language(Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 31 bytes

```
f=AlphabeticOrder[#<>#2,#2<>#]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc5BCsIwEAXQvacICXQVCHSrFT2AKG5LF5M4oTGmLWmsYOjZY9O6@vMfDHwHoUUHwShISVfn19CCxKVe/QN9zQ5HVnJWLtEUaQDjR1KRGClY2SPlhL6xmwydOYnUqSfobE4tEKnEb5A4hkw5Jf7ZKgsZ7afT/YagMsB2rw90noW444R@xP3uAkOtyelEGCk4WYc0Qty86UL6AQ)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 4 bytes

```
₌Jp>
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJ+IiwiIiwi4oKMSnA+IiwiIiwiXCJhXCIsIFwiYlwiID0+IDFcblwiYWNcIiwgXCJhXCIgPT4gMFxuXCJiZWtja2FcIiwgXCJrd25mb2VcIiA9PiAxXG5cImJlenRiZXN0XCIsIFwiYmVzdGJlXCIgPT4gMFxuXCJtY2phZlwiLCBcIm1jXCIgPT4gMVxuXCJha2JvZVwiLCBcInVlbnZpXCIgPT4gMSJd)

A port of python is one byte shorter because of the niceness of parallel apply.

### Explained

```
₌Jp>
₌  >  # check whether
J    # the joining of the two strings
  >  # is greater than
 p   # the prepending of the two strings
```

For a more straightforward approach:

### [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
@Ṙ*ƒ<
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyJ+IiwiIiwiQOG5mCrGkjwiLCIiLCJbXCJhXCIsIFwiYlwiXSA9PiAxXG5bXCJhY1wiLCBcImFcIl0gPT4gMFxuW1wiYmVrY2thXCIsIFwia3duZm9lXCJdID0+IDFcbltcImJlenRiZXN0XCIsIFwiYmVzdGJlXCJdID0+IDBcbltcIm1jamFmXCIsIFwibWNcIl0gPT4gMVxuW1wiYWtib2VcIiwgXCJ1ZW52aVwiXSA9PiAxIl0=)

Takes input as a list of strings.

### Explained

```
@Ṙ*ƒ<
@     # vectorised lengths
 Ṙ*   # reverse that, and pairwise repeat the input strings that many times
   ƒ< # reduce by lexographic less than
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 11 bytes

```julia
a\b=a*b<b*a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TU1LDoIwFFzbU8wSCCzcW2M8hwl5rzySQimmLUq8PNaYKJtJ5j8sztJx3Ta6saaKT1zR1s8BSWJqDUWB9QhCnbNeYlGqA9XgGm2NFRrx7mwqfuFsXyhGCQl5EFrjTiFKcZ1nV6@lEt9tBEbTNGeksIgiA/rSnlwUxTKakTA@fT/LLsfySpxv8AGWfWUyA/WYzH515NxexD/sX30D)

Another port of loopy walt's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259989/97916).

Answer (score 4):

## [Go](https://go.dev), 36 bytes

```go
func(a,b string)bool{return a+b<b+a}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVDBSsQwFMRj8xWPItKyqbh4EbEePQt71MV9qUmJTZOSpCu47Jd4KYIftX6NSbu6vSQzyczLZD6_ajMclh1WDdYcWpSayLYz1l-movXpP3HeSl27lGzRgii_ey-Km8O56HWVIWUw3efMGLWz3PdWAy7YHVvgftL-nF1E8fhElsOOOAe3JWwQGBRFcQ_e9pxgBThRgcpxwngTkkHzroXhMx3jH55x5yEujM8tbfWGAtpqPrVhwd1zvZWn0w0RxsILVVLzmMSiDg2sOiV95hyF9FmnMWciJFevY9iHEWXRkZMkfJuOzknwdLWmf3B5gtdrktioWnWhIZ-JWFce7I-RKh0ptRRsWYahe3Ksaxim_Rc)

Port of Loopy's Python answer.

#### [Go](https://go.dev), 81 bytes

```go
import."strings"
func f(a,b string)bool{return Repeat(a,len(b))<Repeat(b,len(a))}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVDBSsQwFMRj8xWPHqSBVBQvItajZ3WPurhJ96XEpklJUgWX_RIvi-BH-Cn6NSbtLttL8mbyZjLM51djdz89r1veIHRcGaK63rpwlssu5N9DkOXV78OB88Ep0_icyMHUIAvOBEwcFdbqjcMwOAOP2CMP8VWjKQSlN3tCjASndDsZ_52cjkbp34LChngP1xWsOAgoy_IWghuQ8Br4BCXXHonANsaF9t1Ii7M9gR9BoA-QDoFzSVe_cgldPXdtRVQPaN7UkV0RaR28MK0MpiSOm1jLotcqFN4zyJ9NnnJmUqFej2HvxqlICkqyWAgbldPC0_mSHcaL43i5JJlLW4s-dheKsUga5fcJapMgcwxcVUXTLdnXtdtN9z8)

A more literal interpretation of the question.

Comment: Is the `import` required? It [seems to work](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=TVDBSsQwEMVj8xVDD9K66aIIImI9ehb2qIub1EmJTZOSpAou-yVeFsGPWr_GpO2yvWTmTd57vJnvn9rsDxcdqxpWI7RMaiLbzli_TEXr0wlA6ryVunbpb-9FcXs4F72uQGSMchi_cm6M2lr0vdXAFvyeL9huZP-d3Qz06J7lsCXOwV0JGwYciqJ4AG97JKwCNkLBlEPCsQmhoPnUwuCMx_HLc3Qe4sNxLmmrdyagreauDQ_qHvWHPE03RBgLr1RJjTGJZTosP624XHVK-sw5CumLTmPeREhUb0PoI-lxmGTRISdJOAMdnEbi8-WaHturU3u9JomNrFUXTHw2nC8P8qcIlY6QWgq2LIPpjkzn2-_H-g8) without it.

Comment: When I "Attempt This Online" for the first one (the second one works)  I just get errors:`../code.go:12:21: undefined: Split
../code.go:13:12: undefined: Fields`

Comment: @Noodle9 runner was missing some boilerplate, it's fixed now

Comment: @bigyihsuan If you have to import modules for your answer to work you **must** include that code as part of your answer, you can't just tuck them away in the header.

Comment: @Noodle9 (for the first answer) The imports are for the main function *only* as utility to run the test cases. It's not used for anything else, not even for the solution.

Comment: @bigyihsuan Then you have to put with the main program. You can't have imports in the header.

Comment: @Noodle9 This is a limitation with Golang: imports *must* be at the top of the file (so in the header in ATO), after the `package` declaration, and before any other code. If you put imports anywhere else, it generates a syntax error. If the Go compiler encounters code before import statements, then it considers those imports as code and thinks that you are trying to declare something using `:=` syntax outside of a function body, which is not allowed in Go.

Comment: @bigyihsuan But you're using `string` in both of your answers but only put the `import` in the second one. And it clearly doesn't work without it as per the errors from before.

Comment: @Noodle9 `string` is the built-in Golang type for a string of characters. `strings` (note the plural) is the name of a string-handling package in the standard library. They are *not* the same.

Answer (score 3):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 18 bytes

```
$[a b]-><a++b b++a
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?yqDRpR)

Port of loopy walt's [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259989/97916).

Answer (score 3):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 7 bytes

```
‹⁺θη⁺ηθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMntbhYIyCntFijUEchQ1NHAczO0FEo1NTUtP7/Pzc5KzGNKzf5v25ZDgA) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs a Charcoal boolean, i.e. `-` if `a'<b'`, nothing if not. Explanation: Another port of @loopywalt's Python answer.

```
  θ     First string
 ⁺      Concatenated with
   η    Second string
‹       Is less than
     η  Second string
    ⁺   Concatenated with
      θ First string
        Implicitly print
```

There are four cases:

- One of `a` and `b` is a repetition of the other. In this case, `a'=b'`, but `a+b=b+a`, so the result is correct.
- One of `a` and `b` is the prefix of the other, but the other is a prefix of its repetition. In this case the tie between `a'` and `b'` can always be broken before the length of `a+b`. Suppose `a` is a prefix of `b` is a prefix of `a'`, then `a+b` is also a prefix of `a'`, and `b+a` is a prefix of `b'`, so the result is correct.
- One of `a` and `b` is the prefix of the other. In this case the tie between `a'` and `b'` can always be broken before the length of the longer of `a` and `b`. Suppose `a` is a prefix of `b`, then `a+b` contains enough copies of `a` to break the tie with `b`, so the result is correct.
- Otherwise, `a` and `b` break the tie anyway before the length of the shorter of the two, so again the result is correct.

6 bytes by using JSON input:

```
‹ΣθΣ⮌θ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMntbhYI7g0V6NQU0cBRAellqUWFacC@UBg/f9/dLRSbnJWYpqSjgKQoRQb@1@3LAcA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  θ     Input pair
 Σ      Joined
‹       Is less than
     θ  Input pair
    ⮌   Reversed
   Σ    Joined
        Implicitly print
```

9 bytes for the naïve version:

```
‹×θＬη×ηＬθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvRMMntbhYIyQzN7VYo1BHwSc1L70kQyNDU1NHASKYARcs1AQC6///c5OzEtO4cpP/65blAAA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
  θ         First input
 ×          Repeated by
    η       Second input
   Ｌ        Length
‹           Is less than
      η     Second input
     ×      Repeated by
        θ   First input
       Ｌ    Length
            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E (legacy)](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands/2649a799300cbf3770e2db37ce177d4a19035a25), <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Â‚J`‹
```

-1 byte porting [*@loopyWalt*'s Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259989/52210), so make sure to upvote that answer well!

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//cNOjhlleCY8adv7/H62UmKyko5SoFAsA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/w02PGmZ5JTxq2Plf5390tFKiko5SklKsDpCVDGQmgplJqdnJ2SCZ7PK8tPxUqFhVSVJqcQlIPZBKgojmJmclpgGFcpMhZmQnAZXrKJWm5pVlQkQghsYCAA).

**Original straight-forward 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer:**

```
€gR×`‹
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//UdOa9KDD0xMeNez8/z9aKTFZSUcpUSkWAA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/0dNa9KDDk9PeNSw87/O/@hopUQlHaUkpVgdICsZyEwEM5NSs5OzQTLZ5Xlp@alQsaqSpNTiEpB6IJUEEc1NzkpMAwrlJkPMyE4CKtdRKk3NK8uEiEAMjQUA).

**Explanation:**

Uses the legacy version of 05AB1E, built in Python, which allows for comparisons on strings.

```python
Â       # Bifurcate the (implicit) input-pair; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
 ‚      # Pair the pair with its reversed pair
  J     # Join each inner pair together to a string
   `    # Pop and push the strings to the stack
    ‹   # Check if the first is smaller than the second
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)

€g      # Get the length of each inner string of the (implicit) input-pair
  R     # Reverse this pair
   ×    # Repeat the strings in the (implicit) input-pair that many times
    `‹  # Same as above
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

---

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

Porting [@JonathanAllan's Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260022/52210) gives an alternative 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage) answer, which only works in the new version of 05AB1E.

```python
Σδ∍}Q
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//3OJzWx519NYG/v8frZSYrKSjlKgUCwA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfaXL/3OLz2151NFbG/hf5390tFKiko5SklKsDpCVDGQmgplJqdnJ2SCZ7PK8tPxUqFhVSVJqcQlIPZBKgojmJmclpgGFcpMhZmQnAZXrKJWm5pVlQkQghsYCAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Σ       # Sort the (implicit) input-pair by:
 δ      #  Map over the (implicit) input-pair with the current string as argument:
  ∍     #   Extend/shorten the current string of the map to the same length as the
        #   current string of the sort-by
}       # After the sort-by:
 Q      # Check if the sorted pair is equal to the (implicit) input-pair
        # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 82 bytes

```c
t;*p;*q;f(a,b){for(t=3,p=a,q=b;*p==*q&&t;!*++p?--t,p=b:0)!*++q?--t,q=a:0;t=*p<*q;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVHLbsIwELzzFdtIoDwcNRT1UIzbQ9Vb/6BBlW0cmgbysikIlF9vuuQlQI2UtXdmPJuMpb@Wsq4NdXPqFjSyORHOKcpK27AZyRknBRNIMuYWk4mhd67n5S@@b5AT88A590XTF4zPA2qYmy/QqKrj1MCWx6ntwGkE@CDgglHafPKPJTA4vVvcIoBVNotQiUx4tz0agcqm2cpvHrXCRGTKquiNnejtRKtqarJPIxS3bhrdOq9m2an0J74wAnXIlTRq1TpNCQQEhjrthDJLtQH5xUsXq5KJKlu9FR7eHsLD0yu@jzjgsp/1YzBTsM@z4nSlDngsoN12ATo@qiyy@69w7jvAHRAKnteo@zSHCDhadak2giW95kXPi/940Ei3t36NK8SHVG4P5iVKItsKrfFGh/jH3Qb8ZxivYKzDFEFOQBDQZAhLM6aW3ZyqqaUyuzLFKEZV/SujDV/r2t//AQ)

*Based on [loopy walt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/107561/loopy-walt)'s [Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259989/9481)*

Answer (score 3):

## Excel, 12 bytes

```
=A1&B1<B1&A1
```

Input is in the cells `A1` and `B1`. Excel uses `&` for concatenation.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: this is quite the answer.. Excel!? I have respect for you! :D  such a marvelous idea!

Comment: I'd say this is more VBA than Excel, but this is nice, anyway.

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 35 b-bwytes =￣ω￣=

`lambda{|a, b|"#{a}#{b}"<"#{b}#{a}"}`

[Yiff yiff, this is a furrendly conversion of the python tail wag!](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/63383017#63383017)

Comment: Well that just happened

Comment: Welcome to Co...wait I know you!

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno) `D`, \$ 8 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 6.58 bytes

```
rZP.JAu<
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abSSi1LsgqWlJWm6FiuKogL0vBxLbSBcqOiCVdFKiclKOkqJSrEQEQA)
or [verify all test cases](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_abRSilLsds9qx_ioTKOoyqqSKB8lBV1dXTsFpSifpaUlaboWK4qiAvS8HEttINxFUd4QxoKblYkKSRDFJUWlqVyJyQqJEG5aYk5xKldSanZydqJCdnleWn4qkrqk1KqSpNTiEgUQkZSKrCU3OSsxTSE3GdnU7CSg7tLUvLJMhCjEBQA)

Direct port of Kevin Cruijssen's 05AB1E answer, which is a port of loopy walt's Python answer.

##### Explanation

```python
rZP.JAu<  # Implicit input
rZP       # Pair with reverse
   .J     # Join each inner list
     Au   # Dump onto stack
       <  # Check if less than
          # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 32 bytes

```
¶
$'¶$'$`¶$`
O`.+¶
M`(.+)¶\1$
^0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P//0DYuFfVD21TUVRKAZAKXf4KeNlDMN0FDT1vz0LYYQxWuOIP//3OTsxLTuHKTAQ) Explanation: Based on @loopywalt's Python answer.

```
¶
$'¶$'$`¶$`
```

Create a list of `a+b`, `b+a`, `a+b`.

```
O`.+¶
```

Sort the first two elements of the list.

```
M`(.+)¶\1$
^0
```

Check that the last two elements are different.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

```
<sQs_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/36Y4sDj@//9opcRkJR0FpUSlWAA)

Port of [@loopyWalt](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/259989/52210)'s python answer. Takes the input as a list of two strings `[a,b]`.

#### Explanation

```
<sQs_Q    # implicitly add Q
          # implicitly assign Q = eval(input())
<         # lexicographically compare
 sQ       # sum of Q
   s_Q    # sum of the reversal of Q
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://www.gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 10 bytes

```
gt.*cx*^Rv
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNxczcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRMDS0pI0XYs1abbpJXpayRVacUFlEKGbzrmJmXkKtgop-VwKCgVFCioKadFKSjpKSrFI_MSkZKBQYhKaIFgsWSkWYtSCBRAaAA)

Takes the input as a list with two values.  I don't like this format so I also solved it with a good io format:

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://www.gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 14 bytes

```
ap<gt<<fmp*^mp
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNs8zcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRACXrq5Cmm1iQZ1NjpFCeomNjZtKbsHS0pI0XYsNIHEbkFhaboFWHEz4pmFuYmaegq1CSj6XgkJBkYKKQpqCUmJSshKIVEIRU4JIQDQuWAChAQ)

Honorable mention to:

```
ap~<l2 gt<<F$mp
```

which is 1 byte longer.

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://www.gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 13 bytes

```
gt.*Uc mp*^Sw
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNxczcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRMDS0pI0XYv1abbpJXpaockKuQVaccHlENGbbrmJmXkKtgop-VwKCgVFCioKaQoaSko6SkqayAKJSclAscQkdFGwYLKSJsS0BQsgNAA)

This uses a tuple with two values. It's a compromise between the two formats and is *slightly* shorter than the longer of the two.

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org) + [hgl](https://www.gitlab.com/wheatwizard/haskell-golfing-library), 9 bytes

```
cb cx*^Rv
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m708I7E4OzUnZ8FNxczcgvyiEoXC0sSczLTM1BSFgKLUnNKUVC6oRMDS0pI0XYvVabbJSQrJFVpxQWUQkZvOuYmZeQq2Cin5XAoKBUUKKgpp0UpKOkpKsUj8xKRkoFBiEpogWCxZKRZi1IIFEBoA)

This outputs a comparison (3 values) instead of a boolean (2 values).
This is shorter than the first answer, however the output format isn't officially permitted in the challenge ([although I haven't got a "No" yet](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/259987/string-comparison/260066#comment572777_259987)).

I actually prefer this format since it's generally more modular and fits in with the systems available in hgl (part of why this is shorter).  The 14 byte answer can also be made to use this format by replacing `gt` with `cp`, but it makes no difference to the byte count.

## Reflection

The 10 byte and 9 byte answers are pretty tight. The 10 byte answer (and the 13 byte answer) could potentially be shorter if `on gt` were given a 2 byte name (`cb` is the 2 byte name of `on cp` and the reason the 9 byte answer is shorter), however it's a bit hard to justify that. A 3 byte name might be useful anyway.

However I am really concerned with improving the 14 byte answer. The other answers are in my opinion an abuse of the format. This is a very simple challenge and if I were to encounter this challenge as a part of a larger challenge there's no way I would get the input in such a format. I'd get it in a format much more similar to what the 14 byte answer expects. The issue that blows up the size of that answer is that in order to thread through two separate arguments, both of which are used twice requires a good deal of glue.  All the other answers benefit from only taking one input, making their glue much simpler.

So what's missing? Well, I have trouble coming up with a good reusable way to combine any of the existing parts. `on gt` doesn't actually help in this one unlike the other ones. And it's hard to make a version of `on` that actually does help. However there are pretty much two salient functions here `gt` and `mp`. All the glue is just a way to combine two functions, so maybe all of it should just be one function.

```
gt+^$mp
```

This would actually make things shorter (a lot shorter) and since it does combine two arguments it seems plausible that it could be reused at some point in the future. It's not a slam-dunk, it's not a clear hole in the language, but it's about the best I can do in this case.

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an array.

```
¬<UÔ¬
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=rDxV1Kw&input=WwpbImEiICJiIl0gLS0tPiB0cnVlClsiYWMiICJhIl0gLS0tPiBmYWxzZQpbImJla2NrYSIgImt3bmZvZSJdIC0tLT4gdHJ1ZQpbImJlenRiZXN0IiAiYmVzdGJlIl0gLS0tPiBmYWxzZQpbIm1jamFmIiAibWMiXSAtLS0%2bIHRydWUKWyJha2JvZSIgInVlbnZpIl0gLS0tPiB0cnVlCl0tbVI) (Includes all test cases)

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 36 bytes

```
[ 2dup append -rot prepend before? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZC9boNAEIR7P8XkAaBwmUh2GaVJY7myUuwdewo5uDv2lqAY8ewEguQiohlpv9HO/jiyGmW@Xt7eX59BOUebkYRVf5LUQZG56zlYzmhJP8soFQs8S@AG3YCXw3johhEEgwlPKIriBJWeN2oX44EdNXnjhr31BD8EF3mnz/BdDWfFKob3Ilr7RW7RvaneLKnL1t/1P3eabzhWfQKlxKFCIVHXa/8Kwy4Kn/Exu@0Rp5YSyvkX)

```
         ! "ac" "a"
2dup     ! "ac" "a" "ac" "a"
append   ! "ac" "a" "aca"
-rot     ! "aca" "ac" "a"
prepend  ! "aca" "aac"
before?  ! f
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) `-m32`, 78 bytes

This is a comparison function, it outputs \$a + b \lesseqqgtr b + a\$, where \$+\$ is string concatenation.

```c
f(a,n,b,m){int c[4][n+m];wcscmp(wcscat(wcscpy(c),b),wcscat(wcscpy(c+2,b),a));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZLLboMwEEX3fMWIKhIE00fSLiqSbKruuu8ioMo2JnEBg7DzaKL8eunwStMUwcwwHN@xruH@ivO6ThxKFGEkd49SGeDLx2ipvDwKdlzzvHSaRE2byi@Hu4S55KrnTZomdd3gVN9IxbNNLGCmTSyL2/XCslDXyqlUzraQsWsdLcArK9QKxkZo80GXEczh@GZTmwBG3iYmUp7SvjwYhmT7kvNPmnRgygphn4JrPTbosQ5rY7pTCdKdnEa5XqxNG6G2clBqbBD7UnAj4k7JfyCA90XyH3qYF0qja2taYRA8FdUyQgubVXa4f52E@@cXfJ5wzOX7dBiWFBU4zUSpYrHHZfdBX85Ay4MoEmfYi3vXN8bnTgCe19IudK7@OkFRq3e3JaLgCmADwP4BzX40fm7@DTzkTCiH4sEPNcOT/sMKZM@OXYuVFSKJY4f2KNMh@tAX4C9gFMNIhwqblAAjoMnZRT2fi6ifc2pjJcymUmiQdaq/eZLRla79fDqp/XdV@DIvM8ml@QE)